# PHP header forcing download does not work in combination with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, html, mod-rewrite

I had the problem that with simple download links the downloaded file ended up with the wrong extension.

`<a href="downloads/track.gpx" download>Download</a>` got interpreted by the browser as plain text and so was downloaded as **track.gpx.txt**.

Therefore I created download.php and the function forceDownload() which looks like this:

```
function forceDownload($file){

    // Check file
    if($file == "" or !file_exists($file) or is_dir($file)){
        return false;
    }

    // Check extension
    $extension = strtolower(pathinfo(basename($file), PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if(empty($extension)){
        return false;
    }

    // MIME-Types
    $mimetypes = array(
        "sql" => "application/sql",
        "gpx" => "application/gpx+xml"
    );

    // Default MIME-Type
    if(!array_key_exists($extension, $mimetypes)){
        $mime = "application/octet-stream";
    }else{
        $mime = $mimetypes[$extension];
    }

    // Output
    $size = filesize($file);
    $basename = basename($file);

    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: {$mime}");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$basename}\"");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Content-Length: {$size}");

    ob_clean();
    flush();

    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

When i call download.php like `<a href="html/download.php">Download</a>` the download starts directly.
To make it look prettier I added to my **.htacces**:
`RewriteRule ^download$ html/download.php` but when I call it now `<a href="download">Download</a>` I get redirected correctly but the download just starts after refreshing the page. Can anybody help me?

## UPDATE

I just created download.php and forceDownload() to get the right extensions. Of course I would prefer to do it with a simple link.

**download.php**

```
<?php
 forceDownload("../downloads/track.gpx");
?>
```

It seems like it works local:

`<a href="downloads/track.gpx" download="track.gpx">Track</a>` => **track.gpx**

`<a href="downloads/db.sql" download="db.sql">Database</a>` => **db.sql**

But online and in mobile browsers I get:

`<a href="downloads/track.gpx" download="track.gpx">Track</a>` => **track.gpx.xml**

`<a href="downloads/db.sql" download="db.sql">Database</a>` => **db.sql.txt**

Tested in Safari and Chrome, same result.

It works also local, online and in mobile browsers with:

```
<a href="html/download.php" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

But not with:

```
<a href="download" target="_blank">Download</a>

(RewriteRule ^download$ html/download.php => just after refreshing)
```

Comment: `<a href="download" target="_blank">Download</a>` might perform as you want. That should initiate load in new window and with a mime type that is just download it should download and close itself.

Comment: Since you didn't mention how you call the function, I tried to call it as `forceDownload('track.gpx');` right after the definition, and when I clicked the link, the download started directly. Did your browser receive the response when you clicked the link?

Comment: Pretty sure all that PHP stuff isn't necessary to begin with ... Make your link `<a href="downloads/track.gpx" download="track.gpx">Download</a>`, and the browser should automatically suggest the file name as specified - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#download